# How to add linked files in a WIX Visual Studio Project to the setup using Heat task

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I have a WIX Visual Studio project in which I have created a folder structure which is to be read by a Heat MSBuild task to generate the .wxs file. Now if I add some files as links to a folder in this structure, the heat task does not generate components for these linked files.

Is it possible to add linked files as components in .wxs using the Heat task?

Comment: Would you like to add the links to files or the files linked to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`heat.exe` does not support this feature today. There is a feature request out there to support it but no one has implemented it... yet.